# Запрос на авторизацию собранный через Chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, requests

Захожу на сайт, открываю инспектор, вхожу на вкладку Networks. Далее логинюсь через сайт и появляется во вкладке network запрос с именем login. В нем находится различная информация и в конце `Request Payload {"username" : "name", "pass" : "1111"}`. Пробую по аналогии создать запрос:

```
head = {
    "username": "name",
    "pass": "1111",
}

json_string = json.dumps(head)
response = requests.post("https://mysite.ru/api/login", data=json_string)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

В ответ получаю 403 Forbidden. Как сделать запрос на авторизацию?

UDP: Когда изменил `https` на `http` то получил сообщение:

```
{
  "message": "Неизвестная ошибка.",
  "status": 3,
  "stackTrace": [
    "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported",
......
```

Я так понимаю `http` не поддерживается =(
UDP2: Такая информация выводится после выполнения запроса

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mysite.ru:443
send: b'POST /api/login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mysite.ru\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.26.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 77\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'
send: b'"{\\"username\\": \\"name\\", \\"pass\\": \\"1111\\"}"'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 \r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 12:20:53 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=...; Path=/; Secure
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: 0
header: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
header: X-Frame-Options: DENY
header: vary: accept-encoding
header: Set-Cookie: session-cookie=...; Max-Age=86400; Path=/
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://mysite.ru:443 "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 403 None
<Response [403]>
https://mysite.ru/api/login
[]
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie XSRF-TOKEN=... for mysite.ru/>, <Cookie session-cookie=... for mysite.ru/>]>
{"timestamp":"2021-09-09T15:20:53.419+03:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"","path":"/api/login"}
```

Comment: не `data=`, а `json=`, там еще на заголовок запроса нужно смотреть, в котором указан тип отправляемых данных

Comment: только, что заработало, когда заменил https на http. Почему из-за этого не работало?

Comment: @gil9red тип `application/json`. У меня работает с `data`

Comment: а может не сработало, вывело сообщение такое, сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: Советую смотреть что requests отправляет, логирование включать так: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4b717491c23b6f2bce3522f55b645971b534c8b6/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10

Comment: обновил, добавил данные, которые выводятся после запроса

Comment: Непонятно... я бы все-таки поменял запрос на `response = requests.post("https://mysite.ru/api/login", json=head)`. А насчет UPD непонятно причем тут GET, если только вы с `https` не поменяли и `post` на `get`: `Request method 'GET' not supported`

Comment: Я вот тоже не понимаю =(

Comment: Возможно не получается зайти из за настройки сервера. Стоит cors same-origin. Не пойму, можно же залогиниться с компьютера, с телефона, а вот с питона нельзя, менял user-agent и тоже не работает

Comment: Запрос с браузера и с питона не отличаются, если одинаково их заполнить. Смотрите в чем разница в запросах между ними. Запросы по браузера и питону вы теперь видите. Возможно, нужно заголовки добавлять, например тот же User-Agent

Comment: Я копирую запрос из инспектора  хрома в json, запускаю и не работает. А с браузера все нормально работает

Comment: Получилось работать с сайтом вытащив куки из браузера и вставив их программе

Comment: Наверное, это не публичный API, раз там куки использовались. Оформите, пожалуйста, сами решение как собственный ответ :)

Comment: Да, публичного возможно нету, руками очень долго выкачивать данные для обработки, хотелось автоматизировать. Решение на данный момент залогиниться через браузер, скопировать куки из request header и вставить их в код. Пробовал куки получать программно, но там только `session-cookie` передается, а `id, u_id, XSRF-TOKEN` не передаются. Хотелось бы конечно автоматизировать, но пока что идей нету